# Most efficient way to join data from two views

Tags: xpages

Folks:

I have recently begun working with xPages.  I have a view of documents that needs to present data from other related documents in six separated columns.  What I am trying is to use a Computed column that does a lookup to a view with a concatenated string.  My intention was to parse this into the 6 columns of data.  It isn't working and it may be silly of me to try referring to a computed column in another computed column.

Another alternative was to have the underlying view present the UNID of the other document and then do a @GetDocField on the xPages view.

So I have two questions:
1) May I programmatically refer to a Computed column in a view from another Computed column?
2) For efficiency, what would be the best way to present data like a 'join' in a view?

I appreciate your attention and help.

Cheers,

John Collis

Comment: Hint: read about old algorithms used with tape drives. They (somewhat) work well with views: slow seek/lookup but fast sequential access.

Comment: Dude.  I'm not that old!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try to “go native” ? You build one view that contains both documents arranged to be in that view after each other. So you have Type1,Type2,Type1,Type2 etc.

Then use a repeat control to render a table or list “joining” the two rows.

This would save you doing tons of lookups.

Eventually you use that view as Json Rest source to do the joining in Json

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The view has returned search results, so I am not sure how I would "pair" the documents together.  I found another way - update the searchable documents with data from the other documents.  However, I am now thinking I need to try something else.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Java bean that returns a list of Java objects that contain your data.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I may need to go that route.